# Not Working Indicator Minbar Application Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, indicator

The appindicator of *Minbar*, an application installed from the Ubuntu Software Center is not working.

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.

Kindly please do tell me if there is a solution.
Thank you!

Comment: I install Pray Times! in firefox, it is showing the time for prayer, it is not exactly the solution but until the problem is solved it might help

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the package *libappindicator1*, log out and log back in. That should fix it. You can install it right from the Ubuntu Software Center, too.

Comment: In my OS this package is already installed, but still the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

any luck in finding this software or a similar one ? if not i found this software and it's working OK https://sourceforge.net/projects/elokabadhan/

[image]

[image]

Comment: pictures added and link contain more information

Comment: This is why I only commented and not flagged it :) upvote from me.